# How can I save my Tkinter program in a text file (checkbox included)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know how can I save my tkinter program into a text file, my program includes a check button so I want to save whatever I pick on the checkbutton and the total price in a text file. Is it possible? The only thing that I know is when you write text on tkinter it'll save as a txt file.

Here's the code that I want to save as .txt file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

FOODS =  {'Vanilla':80.00,
            'Chocolate': 20.00,
            'Strawberry': 40.00,
            'Mango':100.00,
            'Pistachio':35.00
            }
SIZE={'Small':200.00,
            'Medium': 20.00,
            'Large':80.00,
            }
TOPPPINGS={'Marshmallow':20.00,
            'Chocolate chip': 40.00,
            'Sprinkles':100.00,
            'Oreo':35.00,
            'Pearls':200.00}
class IceCream(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Checkout, Exit):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Checkout)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Checkout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Checkout", font="times 40 bold")
        label.pack(pady=50,padx=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Flavours", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=15, y=120) 
        self.sum_total=0
        self.total_lbl=Label(self,font=("arial",17,'bold'),text=f'Total: {self.sum_total}')
        self.total_lbl.place(x=300,y=450)
        size=150
        for j,i in FOODS.items():
            new_var=i
            i=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=j,variable=i,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda i=i,j=new_var: self.receive(i,j)).place(x=10,y=size)
            size+=50
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Size", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(anchor = 'c', x=280, y=135) 
        size2=175
        for l,k in SIZE.items():
            new_var2=k
            k=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=l,variable=k,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda k=k,l=new_var2: self.receive(k,l)).place(x=230,y=size2)
            size2+=50
                      
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Toppings", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=430, y=120) 
        size3=153
        for n,m in TOPPPINGS.items():
            new_var3=m
            m=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=n,variable=m,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda m=m,n=new_var3: self.receive(m,n)).place(x=400,y=size3)
            size3+=50
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Again", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(IceCream))
        button1.place(x=20, y=450)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Exit))
        button2.place(x=200, y=450)
        
    def receive(self,var,val):
        if var.get()==0:
            self.sum_total-=val
        else:
            self.sum_total+=val
        self.total_lbl.config(text=f'Total: {int(self.sum_total)}')
class Exit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Thank you, " + '\n' + "Have a Good Day!!!", font="times 50 bold")
        label.pack(anchor="c", ipady=180,ipadx=0)
        
        
app = IceCream()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: First of all, your start again button doesn't work

Comment: It's not my whole code, it's just part of my code. Don't mind the "Start again" Button, I just want to know how I can save it when I click something on the Checkbox

Comment: Ok I will try to help !!

Comment: In what way do you want to write the total into the file

Comment: can it be like this?
Flavour:
Size:
Toppings:
Total:

Comment: Yeah it can be !! Just wait for some time. I am writing the logic

Comment: Thank you so much for your big help T-T <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

FOODS =  {'Vanilla':80.00,
            'Chocolate': 20.00,
            'Strawberry': 40.00,
            'Mango':100.00,
            'Pistachio':35.00
            }
SIZE={'Small':200.00,
            'Medium': 20.00,
            'Large':80.00,
            }
TOPPPINGS={'Marshmallow':20.00,
            'Chocolate chip': 40.00,
            'Sprinkles':100.00,
            'Oreo':35.00,
            'Pearls':200.00}
class IceCream(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Checkout, Exit):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Checkout)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Checkout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Checkout", font="times 40 bold")
        label.pack(pady=50,padx=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Flavours", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=15, y=120) 
        self.sum_total=0
        self.total_lbl=Label(self,font=("arial",17,'bold'),text=f'Total: {self.sum_total}')
        self.total_lbl.place(x=420,y=450)
        self.item_list=[]
        self.size_list=[]
        self.topping_list=[]
        size=150
        for j,i in FOODS.items():
            new_var=i
            i=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=j,variable=i,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda i=i,j=new_var,k1=j: [self.receive(i,j),self.add_flavours(i,k1)]).place(x=10,y=size)
            size+=50
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Size", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(anchor = 'c', x=280, y=135) 
        size2=175
        for l,k in SIZE.items():
            new_var2=k
            k=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=l,variable=k,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda k=k,l=new_var2,k2=l: [self.receive(k,l),self.add_size(k,k2)]).place(x=230,y=size2)
            size2+=50
                      
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Toppings", font="times 20 bold")
        label.place(x=430, y=120) 
        size3=153
        for n,m in TOPPPINGS.items():
            new_var3=m
            m=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=n,variable=m,font="times 15",offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda m=m,n=new_var3,k3=n: [self.receive(m,n),self.add_toppings(m,k3)]).place(x=400,y=size3)
            size3+=50
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Again", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(IceCream))
        button1.place(x=20, y=450)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", font="times 15",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Exit))
        button2.place(x=200, y=450)
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Place Order", font="times 15",
                            command=self.place_order)
        button3.place(x=280, y=450)
        
    def add_flavours(self,var,val):
        if var.get()==1:
            self.item_list.append(str(val))
        else:
            self.item_list.remove(str(val))
    def add_size(self,var,val):
        if var.get()==1:
            self.size_list.append(str(val))
        else:
            self.size_list.remove(str(val))
    
        #self.total_lbl.config(text=f'Total: {int(self.sum_total)}')
    def add_toppings(self,var,val):
        if var.get()==1:
            self.topping_list.append(str(val))
        else:
            self.topping_list.remove(str(val))
    
    def receive(self,var,val):
        if var.get()==0:
            self.sum_total-=val
        else:
            self.sum_total+=val
        self.total_lbl.config(text=f'Total: {int(self.sum_total)}')
    def place_order(self):
        with open("all_orders.txt",'a') as file:
            file.write('Flavours: '+','.join(self.item_list)+', Toppings: '+','.join(self.topping_list)+', Size: '+','.join(self.size_list)+', Total: '+str(self.sum_total)+"\n")
            self.item_list.clear()
            self.topping_list.clear()
            self.size_list.clear()
            self.sum_total=0
            self.controller.show_frame(Exit)


class Exit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Thank you, " + '\n' + "Have a Good Day!!!", font="times 50 bold")
        label.pack(anchor="c", ipady=180,ipadx=0)
        
        
app = IceCream()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sujay <3, but is there a way to show the name of the item like for example, "Flavours: Strawberry" instead of the their price?

Comment: This answer would be better if it  had more descriptive text. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you did differently.

Comment: Ok @BryanOakley, I am currently busy, I will edit the answer later